# Get only string in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the below strings,

```
DECLARE @Text1 = 'This is the 1st time I found the Car# CAR:8 #NumberIncluded#'
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the character "#"

Answer (score 3):

This is one option of getting it. It first removes anything all the way through `CAR:` and then removes all after any digits in the remaining string.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( x.TruncString, 0, PATINDEX( '%[^0-9]%', x.TruncString))
FROM (VALUES('This is the 1st time I found the Car# CAR:8 #NumberIncluded#'),
            ('This is the 1st time I found the Car# CAR:8 #NumberIncluded# with no ID tied to it, the prices is 588USD for  CAR:8 #NumberIncluded##NumberIncluded#')
     )SampleData(String)
CROSS APPLY( SELECT STUFF( String, 1, CHARINDEX( 'CAR:', String)+3, ''))x(TruncString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest this one:

```
DECLARE @Text1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'This is the 1st time I found the Car# CAR:8 #NumberIncluded#'

DECLARE @Text2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'This is the 1st time I found the Car# CAR:8 #NumberIncluded# with no ID tied to it, the prices is 588USD for  CAR:7 #NumberIncluded##NumberIncluded#'

DECLARE @Text3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'My CAR:A5, CAR:9 AND CAR:10'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text1, PATINDEX('%CAR:[0-9]%', @Text1) + 4, 1)  
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text2, PATINDEX('%CAR:[0-9]%', @Text2) + 4, 1)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text3, PATINDEX('%CAR:[0-9]%', @Text3) + 4, 1)
```

**Expected results**: 8, 8, 9